# Output result not correct

Tags: php

I am using text area to search the number that user can key in 10 mobile numbers maximum on 1 time. When I try to test with 2 numbers, if I key in 1st number which is have its profile in our db the output is correct. But if I key in 1st value with number that not have its profile in our db the output become incorrect and it does not looping the 2nd value. I got an error illegal offset string. Can anyone help me on this case? Thank you in advance

```
if (isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['search'] == 'Search') {
    $police = new police();

    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $searchuser = $_POST['searchby'];

    $_SESSION['searchby'] = $_POST['searchby'];

    $param = explode("\n", trim($_POST['info']));
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($param); $i++) {
        $param[$i] = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), "", $param[$i]);
    }

    try {
        if ($_POST['searchby'] == 'select') {
            throw new Exception("Please select your identity search");
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $errmsg = $ex->getMessage();
        $tbs->VarRef['searchFail'] = 'true';
        $tbs->VarRef['searchFailMsg'] = $errmsg;
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    }

    if (isset($param) && $_POST['searchby'] == 'msisdn') {

        $ptrnmsisdn = "/^(\+?6?01)[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]\-*[0-9]{7,8}$/";

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($param); $i++) {
            $param[$i] = preg_replace("/^(6)(\d+)/", "$2", $param[$i]);
        }

        try {
            if (empty($param)) {
                throw new Exception("Please enter your search");
            } else {
                foreach ($param as $item) {
                    if (!preg_match($ptrnmsisdn, $item)) {
                        throw new Exception("Please enter correct mobile number");
                    }
                }
            }
            $tbs->LoadTemplate('msisdnprofile1.html');
            //$_SESSION["msisdnlist"] = $police->getSubsInfo($param[0],$searchmsisdn);

            try {
                $searchResult = array();
                foreach ($param as $paramValue) {
                    $search = "NRIC";
                    $msisdnList = $police->getSubsInfo($paramValue, $search);
                    $searchResult[$paramValue] = $msisdnList;
                }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                $searchResult[$paramValue] = $ex->getMessage();
            }

            $listMsisdn = "";
            $arryTemp = array();


            foreach ($searchResult as $searchValue => $subValue) {

               array_push($arryTemp, $searchValue);

                $listMsisdn .= '<div>
<h3>' . $searchValue . '</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="300">Mobile Number</th>
        <th width="300">Status</th>
        <th width="300">View</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

';

```
                    $listMsisdn .= '<tr>
```

' . $subValue['msisdn'] . '
' . $subValue['Reg_Status'] . '
';

```
                $listMsisdn .= '     </tbody>
</table>
```

';

```
            }
            $_SESSION['$searchValue'] = $searchValue;
            $_SESSION['$listMsisdn'] = $listMsisdn;
            $_SESSION['$listOfSearchValue'] = $arryTemp;
            $tbs->Show();
            die();

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $user = $_SESSION['username'];
            $errmsg = $ex->getMessage();
            $tbs->VarRef['searchFail'] = 'true';
            $tbs->VarRef['searchFailMsg'] = $errmsg;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Where do you set `$param` ?

Comment: Where is your text area?

Also, if you're expecting a maximum of 10 digits, shouldn't you use input instead?

Comment: Hi @apokryfos I have set it before the if statement

Comment: $param = explode("\n", trim($_POST['info']));
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($param); $i++) {
            $param[$i] = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), "", $param[$i]);
        }

Comment: @cmprogram Not 10 digits, I think he means 10 different phone numbers.

Comment: Can you update your question with how you've set it instead of adding it as a comment?

Comment: @Barmar yes that's what i mean . sorry for the wrong word use there

Comment: @barmar Ahh, fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `try/catch` around the whole `foreach` loop. So if there's an error in any of the parameters, the loop will stop at that point. You need to put it just around the call to `getSubsInfo()` so you can continue the loop with the rest of the `$param` array.

```
    $searchResult = array();
    $search = "NRIC";
    foreach ($param as $paramValue) {
        try {
            $msisdnList = $police->getSubsInfo($paramValue, $search);
            $searchResult[$paramValue] = $msisdnList;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $searchResult[$paramValue] = $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```